# Problem with screw modifier

Tags: modifiers, screw-modifier

I am trying to make a rope with the circle mesh.

First I added an *array modifier* to the circle, then I added a *screw modifier*.

[[image]]

[image]

I was following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7KtPqic3lQ&t=90s) on youtube. Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: It looks like the origin of your object is in the center of one of the circles. Move the whole mesh (in edit mode) so that the origin (the little orange dot) is in the midpoint between all of the circles.

Comment: Thanks, Christopher that worked!